# How to change directory of glusterfs brick?

Tags: glusterfs

I have a glusterfs brick mounted on the following dir:

```
/home/data/bricks/brick1/brick1
```

Now I would like to change it to:

```
/bricks/project/brick1
```

According to the manual one has to migrate the data:

```
 sudo gluster volume replace-brick vol2 /home/data/bricks/brick1/brick1 /bricks/project/brick1
```

This does unfortunatelly not work. I do get the following error:

```
Usage: volume replace-brick <VOLNAME> <SOURCE-BRICK> <NEW-BRICK> {commit force}
```

The syntax looks OK to me, does somebody else see where the problem is? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an action in the end of command: commit or force

E.g:

```
sudo gluster volume replace-brick vol2 /home/data/bricks/brick1/brick1 /bricks/project/brick1 commit
```